# sudo su ask target user's password

Tags: linux, sudo, su

`sudo su` asks for invoking user's password as default sudo behaviour.

With `Defaults rootpw` it will ask root's password.

1. But is there a way, to make `sudo su` behave like `su`?  Like it'll ask password of the user mentioned in the parameter?

Like:

```
sudo su/ sudo su -      # ask root's password
sudo su foo/ sudo su - foo       # ask foo's password
sudo su bar/ sudo su - bar       # ask bar's password
```

2. `Defaults rootpw` will ask root's password for all the rules mentioned in sudoers file. Is it possible to make it ask root's password for only `sudo su/ sudo su -` rule and not other rules? Correct me if I'm wrong here?

Comment: Why?  `su` already does that.

Comment: I have a requirement to block directly running `su` and bring it under control of `sudo`.

Comment: *I have a requirement to block directly running `su` and bring it under control of `sudo`.*  Whoever came up with that requirement is clueless.  Do you really have shared accounts where multiple people have the password for the same account?  `sudo` is designed to allow logged access to shared accounts without having to share the password - because shared passwords **destroy** security by breaking [nonrepudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation) - when passwords get shared, you **can't** prove who did something.  It looks like you're requirement is likely entirely backwards.

Comment: sorry for late response. The customer's response was they are disabling direct root login and want to use sudo su only to login to root. That too from users in the wheel group only. But wanted the password of the target user rather than current user. However without finding a solution, we pushed back stating it as a limitation for now.